# Rspec: Checking the content of a system call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a Rake task in my Rails project which executes `openssl` through a `system` call.

The code looks like this:

`system('bash', '-c', 'openssl cms -verify...')`

I need to run the command in `bash` rather than `dash` (which is default on Ubuntu) to use process substitution in the command.

I need to create a test with rspec which checks that, in this case, the argument `verify` was passed as expected.

I have tried the following:

```
expect(Kernel).to receive(:system) do |args|
  expect(args[2]).to match(/verify/)
end
```

However, this only gives me the third letter in the first string sent to system - i.e. the letter `s` from `bash` - rather than the third argument sent in the system call.

What am I doing wrong here?  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Args are being passed to the block as sequential arguments, so if you want to treat them as an array, you need a splat operator in `do |*args|`:

```
expect(Kernel).to receive(:system) do |*args|
  expect(args[2]).to match(/verify/)
end
```

Just to take a step back, it's important to understand how block arguments work, since they are different from methods. For example:

```
def my_fn(*args)
  yield(*args)
end

my_fn(1,2,3) { |args| print args }
# => 1

my_fn(1,2,3) { |a, b, c| print [a,b,c] }
# => [1,2,3]

my_fn(1,2,3) { |*args| print args }
# => [1,2,3]
```

So if you did `do |args|` (without the splat), you are assigning the `args` variable to the first argument passed to the block (`"bash"`) and ignoring the other arguments.

Comment: If the last argument is the important one then `expect(Kernel).to receive(:system) do |*,last_cmd|` makes this a bit clearer than `args[2]` as well